# Snaphot repository issue

Tags: maven, archiva

We have installed Archiva with the two repositories set by default.

Here is my **settings.xml**:

```
<server>
   <id>mycompany-release</id>
   <username>admin</username>
   <password>******</password>
</server>
<server>
   <id>mycompany-snapshots</id>
   <username>admin</username>
   <password>******</password> 
</server>

<mirror>
   <id>mycompany-release</id>
   <url>http://X.X.X.X:8080/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
   <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
<mirror>
   <id>mycompany-snapshots</id>
   <url>http://X.X.X.X:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
   <mirrorOf>apache.snapshots</mirrorOf>
</mirror>

<profile>
    <id>repo</id>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
           <id>mycompany-release</id>
           <url>http://X.X.X.X:8080/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
           <releases>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
           </releases>
           <snapshots>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
           <id>mycompany-snapshots</id>
           <url>http://X.X.X.X:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
           <releases>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
           </releases>
           <snapshots>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
           </snapshots>
    </repository>
   </repositories>      
</profile>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>repo</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

I have a parent project that I use to set the common configuration for all the projects. The version of this parent project is 1-SNAPSHOT. So, in all the other projects, the parent section points to this parent project with version 1-SNAPSHOT (without relative path element). If I deploy my parent project to the archiva repository, it is there. If I try to run any command on another project, as mvn clean, it works since the parent project was installed during deployment. But, if I delete manually the parent project from my local repository and try to run the same command, Maven returns an error saying :

> Non resolvable parent POM:  Could not find artifact
>   com.mycompany:Parent:pom:1-SNAPSHOT in mycompany-release
>   (http://X.X.X.X:8080/archiva/repository/internal/) and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

It seems that the parent project is looked up in the release repository while I expected it's looked up in the snapshot repository.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT:** Here is one part of the child POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>child</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

If I remove the parent section and run mvn help:effective-pom, I get (only repositories is shown):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>mycompany-release</id>
      <url>http://X.X.X.X:8080/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>mycompany-snapshots</id>
      <url>http://X.X.X.X:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

**NOTE:** if I replace the parent version by 1 (instead of 1-SNAPSHOT), it works.

Comment: Please provide `pom.xml` for the child project.

Comment: I'd say that it is the rest that is needed =) Can you execute `mvn help:effective-pom` and post output (`<repositories>` section should be enough).

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov I can't run mvn help:effective-pom, I get the same error concerning the parent.

Comment: Just remove the `<parent>` section and run.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Ok, it's done. I see that the private repositories appear as expected.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache if you have got an answer, you can post the answer and accept it.

Comment: @Nishant I don't have the answer. I said "It's done." concerning the comment of Andrew.

Comment: It's strange..  With this configuration Maven should look for your parent artifact only in snapshot and central repositories. Can you post output of `mvn -X package`?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov I found the solution. Thanks to your tip concerning the full debug logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the issue. The problematic line in the **settings.xml** is:

```
<mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
```

Indeed, it caused Maven to consider the **mycompany-release** repository as a mirror of **mycompany-snapshots** repository. But, this repository doesn't mirror snapshots. I replaced this line by:

```
<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
```

Now, the **mycompany-release** repository mirror only the Maven central repository and not the **mycompany-snapshots** repository, so it looks up the snapshots artifacts in the **mycompany-snapshots** repository.

Thanks Andrew for your help! I didn't now there was a possibility to display the full log.